# Is this how the WIF Extensions for SAML2 are supposed to work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, wif, saml-2.0

I downloaded the [WIF Extensions for SAML2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/card/archive/2011/05/16/announcing-the-wif-extension-for-saml-2-0-protocol-community-technology-preview.aspx) a few days ago and have been experimenting with them. The samples in the download use a WebForms application, and I am trying to figure out how to use them in MVC3.

I am currently able to auth against the sample Identity Provider that comes with the download, using this:

```
Saml2AuthenticationModule.Current.SignIn(
    "~/sign-on/saml2/success", "urn:samples:identityprovider");
```

I have an action method at the "sign-on/saml2/success" route / URL, and when the application flow reaches it, the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` is indeed an instance of `IClaimsIdentity`. Although the `Identity.IsAuthenticated` equals true, the `Identity.Name` is an empty string. (This will be problematic in our app, which so far has used FormsAuthentication, and relies on `Identity.Name` to resolve to a user account in the db.)

I also see that there are 4 new cookies at this point:

1. FedId
2. FedAuth
3. FedAuth1
4. [fourth cookie name is a GUID, changes for each SSO]

My inclination at this point is to delete these 4 cookies and use the claims `NameIdentifier` to create a new account in our app (unless one already exists), and then use FormsAuthentication to write a .ASPXAUTH cookie for the user.

The first affiliate IdP we will be integrating with uses Shibboleth, and they do not yet implement SingleLogOut. So my assumption is that the following would have no effect when we begin testing this integration:

```
Saml2AuthenticationModule.Current.SignOut("~/sign-off/saml2/success");
```

So, manually deleting the 4 cookies is the only way we would be able to get the `Identity.IsAuthenticated` back to a false value.

**Am I going about this in an incorrect fashion? Are there any implications of trashing the IClaimsIdentity after it has been consumed and transferred to FormsAuthentication, that I am not considering?**